# how to resize this wpf button

Tags: c#, wpf

I am not good at WPF and I am struggling with this a bit.  I have a WPF window that has the following code:

```
 <ContentControl.Content>
            <Button Name="btnUpdateCommand" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="2" Command="{Binding UpdateCommand}" Height="23" Margin="0,4">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="txtUpdate" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding InstallButtonText}"  DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="5,2,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FormCloseCountDown}"  DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="5,2,0,0"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
        </ContentControl.Content>
```

How do a resize btnUpdateCommand when I have localization text.   I tried changing the alignment of the TextBlock etc. but no joy.
As an example this is what the button look like when it has english
[image]
And this is what the button looks like when it has french
[image]
What am I missing?

Here is the entrie XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UpdateCheckModule.UpdateCheckProgress"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
         Height="250" Width="500">

<Grid Margin="10">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="175"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="10"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>



    <ContentControl Grid.Row="0">
        <ContentControl.Content>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="95"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="23"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="18" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}" Grid.Row="1" />
                <Border Grid.Row="2" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="DarkGray">
                    <ProgressBar  Value="{Binding ProgressPercentage}" Foreground="#FF10AAE7"></ProgressBar>
                </Border>

            </Grid>
        </ContentControl.Content>
        <ContentControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HideProgress}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ContentControl.Style>
    </ContentControl>

    <ContentControl Grid.Row="0">
        <ContentControl.Content>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="9*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="115"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="18" />
                <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/UpdateCheckModule;component/sedv2.ico" Grid.Column="1"></Image> 
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ReleaseNotesText}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="DarkGray" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DeploymentManifest.ReleaseNotes}" Background="White" Margin="5"></TextBlock>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </Grid>

        </ContentControl.Content>
        <ContentControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HideProgress}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ContentControl.Style>
    </ContentControl>

    <Button Name="btnSkip" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="2" Content="{Binding SkipButtonText}" Width="100" Command="{Binding SkipCommand}" Height="23">
    </Button>

    <ContentControl Grid.Row="2">
        <ContentControl.Content>
            <Button Name="btnUacRestartCommand"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="2" Width="175" Command="{Binding UacRestartCommand}" Height="23">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{Binding Shield}" DockPanel.Dock="Left"></Image>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding AdminInstallButtonText}"  DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="5,2,0,0"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FormCloseCountDown}"  DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="5,2,0,0"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
        </ContentControl.Content>
        <ContentControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RequireUAC}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ContentControl.Style>
    </ContentControl>

    <ContentControl Grid.Row="2">
        <ContentControl.Content>
            <Button Name="btnUpdateCommand" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="2" Width="175" Command="{Binding UpdateCommand}" Height="23">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding InstallButtonText}"  DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="5,2,0,0"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FormCloseCountDown}"  DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="5,2,0,0"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
        </ContentControl.Content>
        <ContentControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RequireUAC}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ContentControl.Style>
    </ContentControl>






</Grid>
```

Comment: Your problem is not clear, I tested your code and the button gets resized to fit the text inside the text block.

Comment: I added the images to my original post to illustrate my point.

Comment: It's also unclear why the Button is in a ContentControl. That doesn't seem to make sense. Besides that, there seems to be Button Style that adds the icon. Maybe the problem is due to that Style.

Comment: The size of controls is very much influenced by its parents. The code snippet you show seems fine. What are the parents of the ContentControl in which the button lives?

Comment: @gofa3 I suspect you are right.  I just added the entire XML to my op.   I suspect it's the grid row thats causing this problem.

Answer (score 4):

You're explicitly setting the `Width` of the `Button` (to `175`). Remove this attribute; this will allow the `Button` to determine its own optimal width.

While you're at it, remove the `DockPanel.Dock` attributes on the `TextBlock`s; these attributes do nothing since the `TextBlock`s are inside a `StackPanel`, not a `DockPanel`.